# How to check if triggered checkbox is checked in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In my Lightning component I iterate over a custom wrapper to print a list of checkboxes on my page, now in my `selectoptionvalue` I need to determine if the triggered checkbox was checked or unchecked. How can I do this?

**Component**

```
<input
aura:id="inputCheckbox"
onchange="{!c.selectoptionvalue}" 
type="checkbox" 
id="{!v.value}"
/>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    selectoptionvalue : function(component, event, helper) {

        console.log("isChecked:" + event.getSource().get("v.checked"));
...
```

I'm not sure I'm using the right string as nothing is returned in my console log if I use `event.getSource().get("v.checked")`.

Comment: why are you not using `lightning:input` ?
are you even sure that selectoptionvalue  is being called?, if yes, did you try adding a breakpoint to check why your console.log might not be working?

Comment: It definitely is, if I remove the console log then all my logic beneath it starts running.

Comment: so, then what happens if you add a break-point? what seems to be the error?

Comment: also, have you considered using LWC's instead?

Comment: I would try stringifying the event so you can see what is actually in it

Comment: I'm not using lightning:input because I have html5 `data-attributes` that I couldn't consistently get working. I've added a breakpoint after the console.log line but it doesn't even reach that line when the JS method is invoked, as soon as I remove the console line it does though. I don't really want to go down the LWC approach (although it would be better) now as the whole development of this piece is too far along to redevelop.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Appending `JSON.stringify` to the line still doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like `event.getSource().get("v.checked")` isn't available on the tags used. If I switch to `lighting:input` it works as expected.

In the end I used document.querySelector to get the element and check its value as I needed to input tags to support additional data attributes.

Something like this (note this is in a loop)

```
checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
        console.log('checkbox is marked');
    }
}
```